# Point H/V capped at value 32768 pre-scaling

Tags: adobe-pdf-library

The Point H/V properties from a given Path in a PDF seem capped at value of 32768 pre-scaling from a matrix transform.  I'm trying to read the Point information for certain PDF's where it seems to be limiting the Point data incorrectly.  When I try transforming the point using transform matrix for the associated element, the matrix appears to be applied to the capped value rather than the true underlying value.  A given point as a reported by the library might have an H or V value greater than 32768 where the scaling value might be something like 0.006.

Is there a way to access a Point with a H or V value greater than 32768 before it is scaled?  Or even getting the correct scaled value would be okay.

I've seeing this behavior in version 15.0.4PlusP4k and other 15.0.4.x versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is are two interfaces to access the points in a path. PDEPathGetData returns a list of ASFixed values, and hence is limited to the ASFixed range (as you found). PDEPathGetDataEx (PDEPath path, ASReal *Data, int DataLen) will return the same array of Points, but they will not be limited to the ASFixed range.

Also, I should point out that Datalogics Support is always available to answer these types of questions from customers. Both on-line, and by Phone.